How to create a splash screen in perl and GTK3 for a flatpack program?
I just created (and published at https://www.pling.com/p/2230712/) a theme for the excellent open source audio player gmusicbrowser, and now, since it takes 6~7 seconds to load, I would like to complete my work with a splash screen, but I am not a developer. gmusicbrowser is written in perl and uses GTK3.
Of course, I have read and tested the scripts offered at How to create a custom splash screen for a program?, but not only do they do not work as is, under ubuntu 24.10, GNOME Shell, ubuntu session on Xorg, if Firefox is not already open, but they do not work at all with gmusicbrowser installed by flatpack (the command is /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=gmusicbrowser --file-forwarding org.gmusicbrowser.gmusicbrowser), which would be best, not even with gmusicbrowser installed by .deb.
Paolo Molaro wrote a tutorial (http://pwet.fr/man/linux/entreprises_bibliotheques/pm/gtk_cookbook/) but it is very old.
Thanks for a helping hand, for me and the community!
(And sorry for posting at How to create a custom splash screen for a program? before daring to create a new topic... )

might it bee better to ask your question on flathub? This doesn't appear to be Ubuntu specific.

"Le parcours du combattant" ("The obstacle course"), as we say in French... But you are certainly right, and I thank you for your attention. Here, in France, it's getting late (10:42 p.m.) but I'll try to discover "Flathub Discourse" tomorrow.
Thank you and good night... or good day, depending on your country and your habits!

de rien (as we say in la Charente)  bonne soirée

Ah! ah! the world is small, as we answer in the Loiret !

bonne chance avec votre question sur Flathub

It's indeed an obstacle course, just to post a question to https://discourse.flathub.org: you first have to be appreciated, which obviously takes more than 9 hours...
I'll come back to this thread if I end up getting something juicy that might help others, because the subject hasn't interested just me for years, and it's surprising to find almost nothing on the Internet.
See you soon I hope! (as Google Translate says )
